# How to make a call from standard python GAE app to google function with authentication?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-functions

1. I have a google function with removed allUsers permission.
2. I have a standard GAE application written in Python.
3. How to get proper auth token to make http call to the protected google function?

```
        auth_token, _ = app_identity.get_access_token('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform')
        headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer {}'.format(auth_token)}
        result = urlfetch.fetch(
            url='https://us-central1-app_id.cloudfunctions.net/function-name',
            method=urlfetch.POST,
            headers=headers)
```

It looks like there are some answers here https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/authenticating but I could not figure out how to make it working.

Thank you in advance

Comment: My response works for App Engine standard using Python 3.7. If you are using Python 2.7, the metada server cannot be used and the [method you are using](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/appidentity/#asserting_identity_to_google_apis) is the correct one. If you still want to use Python 2.7, can you give more details about the error you are getting?

Comment: I got DNS lookup error for metadata call in standard GAE. Thank you! it looks like I need to upgrade to Python 3.7

Comment: You could use the header `X-Appengine-Inbound-Appid` to verify the origin of the request as per [the docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/outbound-requests). This header can't be modified nor faked when calling GCF, so you can be sure the App in that header is the one making the request. Re-add the AllUsers to the IAM permissions, and return a 403 if the header does not have the proper App.

Comment: Also, if the GCF is making something async, it's better to use PubSub to talk to the function than a direct http call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have followed the documentation you sent and tried to reproduce. I have used this sample for [function to function](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/authenticating#function-to-function) and it worked fine for me. These are the lines within the sample code where the token is obtained:

```
metadata_server_token_url = 'http://metadata/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/identity?audience='

token_request_url = metadata_server_token_url + receiving_function_url
token_request_headers = {'Metadata-Flavor': 'Google'}

# Fetch the token
token_response = requests.get(token_request_url, headers=token_request_headers)
jwt = token_response.content.decode("utf-8")
```

Comment: I tried it but got DNS lookup error for http://metadata in standard GAE